# JVM voxel game engine lag spikes

Tags: performance, voxels, lag, profiling

I'm experiencing short lag spikes after some voxel chunks have been created while not moving the camera around. I profiled the application: the JVM implementation uses a lot more memory, about 2.5 times more, compared to c++ exact implementation. Also, according to the profiler, the cause of the lag is the garbage collector. But there is nothing to collect ! All voxel data is static, references are kept, nothing gets allocated while profiling. I also turned off all the rendering to make sure that native memory is not leaking. Still lagging.

What could be it ? If you need any code, I'll add it here. (Writing in scala)

Answer (score 1):

Ahh. I've been struggling with this problem for a few days. Java 8 update 92 and still parallel garbage collector as default ( . Switching to the newest G1 collector made it all nice and smooth. JVM option: `-XX:+UseG1GC`.